# Wordpress blog pagination not working

Tags: pagination

Please let me know if anyone know ..

```
     <?php
                $per_page = 6;
                $paged    = get_query_var('paged') ? : 1;
                $offset   = (1 === $paged) ? 0 : (($paged - 1) * $per_page) + (($paged - 1) * 2);
                
                 $args = array(
                'post_type'=> 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'orderby' => 'ID',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'author__not_in' => array(1),
                'offset' => $offset,
                  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
                
                );
                $result = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if ( $result-> have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
                          
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" style="float:left;">
                                        <div class="authorname">
                                         <?php //geting here post author name
                                            echo get_the_author(); 
                                            
                                          ?>
                                        </div>
                                               <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                <div class="featured_image">
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                                        <?php
                                                         the_post_thumbnail('full');
                                                         ?>
                                                     </a>
                                                 </div>
                                                 
                                               <div class="excerpt">
                                                    <?php
                                                     $cats = get_the_category($id);
                                                    
                                                    // excerpt of post
                                                    the_excerpt();
                                                    
                                                    ?>  
                                                    
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="category_name">
                                                   <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ): ?>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">
                                                            <?php echo $cat->name; echo ", "; ?>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                               </div>
                                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                <!-- Pagination -->
                                <nav class="pagination">
<?php  previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous', $query->max_num_pages);
if ($paged > 1) echo ' | ';
next_posts_link('More &raquo;', $query->max_num_pages);

echo '<br> Showing ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + 6) . ' of ' . $query->found_posts . ' posts.';
 ?>
</nav>
                                <!-- pagination ends here -->
                    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
                   </div> 
                   </div>
            
          <?php
          
          
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$paged    = get_query_var('paged') ? : 1;
```

To

```
$paged = absint(
    max(
        1,
        get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : get_query_var( 'page' )
    )
);
```

Change

```
$query
```

To

```
$result
```

Final code

```
 <?php
                $per_page = 6;

                $paged = absint(
                                           max(
                                                        1,
                                                          get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : get_query_var( 'page' )
                                               )
                               );
                
                $offset   = (1 === $paged) ? 0 : (($paged - 1) * $per_page) + (($paged - 1) * 2);
                
                 $args = array(
                'post_type'=> 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'orderby' => 'ID',
                'paged' => $paged,
                //'author__not_in' => array(1),
                'offset' => $offset,
                  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
                
                );
                $result = new WP_Query( $args );
                
                    if ( $result-> have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
                          
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" style="float:left;">
                                        <div class="authorname">
                                         <?php //geting here post author name
                                            echo get_the_author(); 
                                            
                                          ?>
                                        </div>
                                               <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                <div class="featured_image">
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                                        <?php
                                                         the_post_thumbnail('full');
                                                         ?>
                                                     </a>
                                                 </div>
                                                 
                                               <div class="excerpt">
                                                    <?php
                                                     $cats = get_the_category($id);
                                                    
                                                    // excerpt of post
                                                    the_excerpt();
                                                    
                                                    ?>  
                                                    
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="category_name">
                                                   <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ): ?>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">
                                                            <?php echo $cat->name; echo ", "; ?>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                               </div>
                                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    
                                <!-- Pagination -->
                                <nav class="pagination">
<?php  previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous', $result->max_num_pages);
if ($paged > 1) echo ' | ';
next_posts_link('More &raquo;', $result->max_num_pages);

echo '<br> Showing ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + 6) . ' of ' . $result->found_posts . ' posts.';
 ?>
</nav>
                                <!-- pagination ends here -->
                    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
                   </div> 
                   </div>
```